# Best way to get "confirm this action"-like functionality in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Good evening,

I'm currently trying to battle my way through learning Prolog, and while I've already gotten well-appreciated help here and I'm certainly better-going than I was at first, I've struck another issue.

I'm currently at a point where I'd need some kind of "ENTER to continue", "ENTER to confirm", "Continue (y/n)?" or similar functionality, but have failed to find anything of the sort myself. I've read up on prologs built-in `read/1` predicate, but after trying to peek at examples and experimenting myself, I've come to the conclusion it might either be more difficult than I first planned it to be in prolog, or I'm simply using the wrong predicate.

I've tried calling `read(X),` on it's own line in my existing predicates, creating "designated" predicates to handle the user input (such as `get_user_input(X):- read(X), input(X).` , and then calling that), and like previously mentioned, looked at examples. But while the program does seem to "stop" when it should, it doesn't seem to accept any kind of user input (as far as I'm understanding it), and as such, I feel like I'm completely and entirely lost at this point.

Any and all help (or pointers) would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you have tried to accomplish this that someone else could test?

Comment: @ScottHunter I did have a look at it earlier, but just had a look at it again and I now see what I missed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `read` reads a term (which is why it is looking for `y` to be a procedure); how you can get Prolog to *not* interpret it may depend on what version of Prolog you are using.  Or you could define `y` as a predicate that takes no arguments and is true.